anacondaでpythonのimportがモジュールがないとエラーになります。pathを通すにはどうすればいいですか？Macです。
anacondaでpythonのimportがモジュールがないエラーになります。
anacondaのpathを確認して通すにはどうすればいいですか？
Macです。
anacondaは再インストールしましたが解決できずにいます。
追記：
失礼しました。
ご指摘のとおり確かにXY問題にとれると思いましたので追記させていただきます。
標準ライブラリはimportできるのですが、下層フォルダ（A,B)にあるファイル（C)で読み込みエラーになります。
環境はjupyter
pythonは3.12
コード：
from A.B import C
エラーメッセージ：
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'A.B'; 'A' is not a package

この辺の記事 MacからAnacondaを完全にアンインストールする３つの方法, 初心者のためのAnacondaインストール(mac編) やご自分で良さそうと思われる情報を参考に、いったん完全にアンインストールしてから再度インストールしてみてはどうでしょう？ 今の質問に書かれた内容では、他の人が貴方の状況を把握して助言・回答するためには、此処はどうなっていますか？とかあれを調べて追記してくださいとか、多数のやり取りが必要になってなかなか進まないと思われます。

ありがとうございます。
完全にアンインストールして、再度インストールしましたがパスが通りません。zshとbashのプロファイルにbinとプログラムフォルダを登録しましたが改善しません。windowsのアナコンダは正常に読み込まれるのでソースに原因はなく、やはりパスに原因があるようです。他追記必要でしたら教えてください。

インストールのために参考にした記事とか実際にどう作業したか・作業結果を確認したか、そして質問のエラーが発生するまでの状況・行った手順(どんなツール・環境・IDEでメニュー等で何を選んだか等も含めて)やソースコード、そして表示されたエラーメッセージをまとめたりせず表示されたままをスクリーンショットでは無くテキストで提示してみてください。これらヘルプ記事を参考に。良い質問をするには？, 再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方, スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？

最初にコメントで書いたように、助言・回答しようとする人が状況と問題を把握してふさわしい回答をなるべく早く出来るようにするためですね。今書かれている質問内容だけでは、貴方自身の個々の状況や、Anaconda,Pythonに関わらないごく一般的な助言・回答が出やすいですし、それを参考に貴方が作業しても、解決しませんでした、という結果になり、それが何回も繰り返される可能性が高いからです。

記載できることは書いておりますので、公開情報にて何かヒントなど頂けるかたにお願いします。
（ビジネス上からソースコード自体を公開することは控えております。）
解決できる保証がないことを理解しております。

Pythonをどのように動かしてますか？ ターミナルで動かしてるなら,  その前に activateしなければ  import失敗するはず。Jupyterなど使っていて import失敗ならどこか壊れてる可能性も

適切な回答をつけるため、質問を編集して質問の範囲を特定の問題に限定し、より詳細な情報をつけてください。

質問の期待値は「pathの確認方法と通し方です。」その回答は難しいのでしょうか。

せめてバージョンやエラーなっているコードとエラーメッセージくらいは提示したらどうでしょうか？
パスワード等の機密情報があれば伏字にするなどやり方はあると思いますよ。
私はMacを持っていないので助けになりませんが

それはテンプレートだから記載するということですか？
コード記載すると１００万行だとしたら、記載したら満足いくのでしょうか。エンジニアなら関係ない労力に時間をかけないと思いますが他人事なのですか？

なぜ１００万行を記載するのかわかりませんが。エラーになっている行だけでも良いと思います。複数あっても関係がありそうな１行だけでも良いと思います。改行なしの一行プログラムであればエラーの発生している部分を自分で切り分けてください。たぶん数行のサンプルプログラムを作成しても再現できるのでしょう。

anaconda python import mac をキーワードに検索してみました。
numpy のある場所とか載っています。
「python入門講座 | Anacondaでpython3をMチップMacにインストールする方法[番外編]」https://the-silkworms.com/pyol_conda_m2mac/3159/

質問者さんが Anaconda の公式のインストール方法にしたがっているとして、それでも問題が起こるようであれば、現状の情報から回答することは難しいです。質問者さんのお手元でどういう異常が起こっているのか分からず、回答者の手元で問題を再現することができないためです。お試しになった手順や出たエラーメッセージ、エラーを起こしているプログラム断片など、質問文を [edit] して情報を追記してみてください。業務上の理由でコードを開示できないのは構いませんので、業務とは関係ない短いコードで同様の問題を再現できないか質問者さんのお手元でお試しください。ヘルプページ「再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方」も参考になるかと思います。

「anacondaでpythonのimportがモジュールがないエラーになります。」の解決方法は「anacondaのpathを確認して通す」ではないだろうと思います。何が起きていて何を解決しようとしているのか想像できない、という感想です。いわゆるXY問題 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2701/#answer-2702 に陥っていて、1行目と2行目に脈絡がないと思いました

下記のサイトにPythonで「3. パスが通っているか」の説明があります。参考になりますか？
[PythonでImportErrorが起きたときの確認事項まとめ - Qiita]
https://qiita.com/ktgwaaa/items/6d1f54d5ff3c4559f96c

下記のサイトにもパスの説明があります。[Pythonでimportの対象ディレクトリのパスを確認・追加（sys.pathなど）- note.nkmk.me]
https://note.nkmk.me/python-import-module-search-path/

例えば料理であれば、レシピの分量と手順を守れば誰でも結果を再現できます。プログラミングやコンピュータも同じで、結果がうまくいかないのであれば途中の過程で何かを間違っている可能性があります。ここにいる回答者は質問者の環境を直接覗き見ることはできないので、その"何か"を突き止めるためにできる限りの情報が必要となります。 (本人が正しく作業を行ったつもりでも、どこかで抜けや間違いをしている可能性があります)

Anacondaの再インストールでエラーがなくなると思ったのは標準モジュールだったからでしょうね？
もしかしたら conda コマンドでインストールする必要があるモジュールだったのではありませんか？

「下層フォルダ（A,B)にあるファイル（C)で読み込みエラーになります。」ということなので、「anacondaのpathを確認して通す」(つまりシェルの環境変数PATHの設定とか？)は全く関係が無いでしょう。「下層フォルダ」というからには「自作モジュール」になるので、その中のフォルダ構成や各フォルダに__init__.pyが存在するか、__init__.pyの記述内容は適切か、といったことが問題でしょう。例えばこんな記事が参考になるのでは？ Pythonの相対インポートで上位ディレクトリ・サブディレクトリを指定, Pythonでサブモジュールを自動でインポートする, jupyter notebook で自作モジュールの読み込み方法

A パッケージの B モジュールにある C 関数をインポートしようとしているが、A はパッケージでないということでしょうかね？

A が何者かを隠されると困ります。今の情報からだとエラーの行の直前で import A; print(A.__file__) を挿入して A がどこのなにを読んでいるのか? それは自分が想定している物なのか? をまず確認するでしょうね。「anacondaのpathを確認して通す」という表現が曖昧すぎて意味がわからない、とも思ってましたが、もしかして「pathの確認方法」というのはそういう話でしたか?

quickquip　さん　ご想像の通りです。
Aフォルダ.Bフォルダ.Cファイルという構造ですが、Aフォルダが読み込めてないとの仮説から、読み込めない理由はPath設定が不十分であり、その確認方法と設定方法を教えてほしいです。
ちなみに、import modules.constants; print(modules.constants.file)の出力は「None」です。（pythonのバージョンは3.12）

実行時のカレントディレクトリとAフォルダがあるディレクトリが異なっている状況だと思われます。

エラーメッセージを見るとAはフォルダとして認識していますが、パッケージではないと言っています。

"読み込めない理由はPath設定が不十分であり、その確認方法と設定方法を教えてほしいです" < すみませんが、結局これがなにを言いたいのか私には分かりません……。"Aフォルダが読み込めてないとの仮説から"も、なにがどうしてその仮説に至ったのか伝ってません。どんな現象を観測したのか? と、それについてどう考えたのか? の区別なく記述も足りなさすぎて「何が起きてるんだ?」レベルです（何通りかの想像はできても、どれが一番ありえそうか? の手がかりがなさ過ぎます）

既出ですが「__init__.pyを持たない（=パッケージでない）ディレクトリをインポートしてしまっている」は想像できますが、その上で **何を回答すると解決するのか?**や、何をわかってもらえたらいいのか? がまったく分からず…

もしも「カレントディレクトリー」を確認する方法を問うているなら Jupyterでなら, セルに %pwd と入力すれば表示できます。移動なら os.chdir('path/to/...')とか(あるいは %cdとか)

Aディレクトリの名前を変更すれば、エラーメッセージは変わると思います。前の方にある kunif さんが張ってくれているリンクを参考にしてフォルダ直下に init.py のファイルを作成すればパッケージとして認識されると思います。環境がわからないので、ファイルの内容はリンクを参考にして記述してください。

①__init__.pyはなくても良いとの記事に基づいています。
https://zenn.dev/knziiy/articles/python-not-need-initpy
②カレントディレクトリの直下にAディレクトリがあります。
③リリースされているバージョンのソースであり動作実績ありと判断しています

試すこともできませんか？

Bフォルダには__init__.pyが存在するので、Aフォルダに__init__.pyを作り実行した結果、「SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence」が１０行程度出力されました

とりあえず import できたということですね

Anacondaの最新の環境で試してみたら[init.py] はなくてもパッケージとして認識してくれました。
Python 3.3以降であればなくても動作するようです。
Pythonのバージョンを再確認したみたらどうでしょうか？
今までのテストはAディレクトリをプロジェクト直下に置いたからパッケージが検索できていましたが、このAディレクトリを他に置きたかったのでしょうか？
それであれば、下記のサイトが参考になると思います。
PYTHONPATH 環境変数へのパスの設定方法をＯＳ毎に説明しています。
「Anaconda仮想環境の環境変数設定 #Python - Qiita」
https://qiita.com/KodaiS/items/5c177dd1b332130e4e26
私はMACを使用したことがないのですが、丁寧に記述してあります。

質問は結局エラーになる以前の問題だったのですかね？
Aフォルダにパッケージを作成したがこのフォルダをPythonに検索してもらう方法を知りたいということだったのですかね？
だからエラーメッセージは提供できなかったのかもしれませんね

下記の Python公式ドキュメントの「3.13.1 Documentation - Python」 に init.py の説明があります。
「Python チュートリアル  - 6.4. パッケージ」
https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages
この中に「ファイルを含むディレクトリをパッケージとしてPython に扱わせるには、ファイル init.py が必要です(より高度な機能 namespace package を使う場合を除く)。」
という記述があります。特に必要ない限りはこのファイルは追加しておいた方が良さそうです。
またこのドキュメントの 6.1.2. モジュール検索パス に検索パスの説明があります。ご参考までに

Condaの仮想環境を使用しているのであれば下記のような方法で環境変数を設定する方法もあるようです。
Anaconda仮想環境の環境変数設定 #Python - Qiita
https://qiita.com/KodaiS/items/5c177dd1b332130e4e26
この中のCondaユーザーガイド (Saving environment variables)
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables
のリンク先のWindowsの説明の下に macOS and Linux についての説明があります。terminal で python を起動する環境（仮想環境）で操作してください。
英語ですが、コマンドやファイルの内容は理解できると思います。
